# Не отправляются сообщения Netty JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, netty

Я передаю ссылку на объект Network в контроллер AuthorizationController, через Main класс приложения. При отправке сообщения методом writeAndFlush ничего не уходит\не приходит на сервер. При подключении через telnet на сервере все сообщения отображаются. Возможно я не правильно передаю Network, поправьте меня пожалуйста.
Код класса Network

```
import io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer;
import io.netty.channel.EventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;
import io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel;
import io.netty.handler.codec.LineBasedFrameDecoder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.string.StringDecoder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.string.StringEncoder;
import io.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler;
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil;

import java.io.*;

public class Network {
    private SocketChannel channel;
    private final String HOST;
    private final int PORT;

    public Network(String host, int port) {
        this.HOST = host;
        this.PORT = port;
    }

    public void connectToServer() {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            EventLoopGroup clientGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
            try {
                Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
                bootstrap.group(clientGroup)
                        .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                        .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                            @Override
                            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                                channel = socketChannel;
                                socketChannel.pipeline()
                                        .addLast(
                                                new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8),
                                                new LineBasedFrameDecoder(8192),
                                                new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8),
                                                new ChunkedWriteHandler(),
                                                new ClientHandler());
                            }
                        });
                ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(HOST, PORT).sync();
                future.channel().closeFuture().sync();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                clientGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }


    public void authorize(String username, String password) {
        channel.writeAndFlush("/authorize " + username + " " + password);
    }
}
```

Код AuthorizationController

```
import Utils.Network;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;


public class AuthorizationController implements Initializable {
    private Network network;
    @FXML
    TextField loginField;
    @FXML
    PasswordField passwordField;


    public void btnLoginOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
        if (loginField.getText().isEmpty() || passwordField.getText().isEmpty()) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "First you need to enter your username and password!", ButtonType.OK);
            alert.showAndWait();
        } else {
            String username = replaceForbiddenSymbols(loginField.getText());
            String password = replaceForbiddenSymbols(passwordField.getText());
            network.authorize(username, password);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

    private String replaceForbiddenSymbols(String str) {
        return str.replaceAll("[^0-9a-zA-Z&!?$#*^]", "");
    }

    public void setNetwork(Network network) {
        this.network = network;
    }
}
```

Код ClientHandler

```
package Utils;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.DefaultFileRegion;
import io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler;
import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;

import java.io.RandomAccessFile;


@Log4j2
public class ClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<String> {

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String msg) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }


    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        if (ctx.channel().isActive()) {
            ctx.writeAndFlush("ERR: " +
                    cause.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " +
                    cause.getMessage() + '\n').addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        }
    }
}
```

Код Main

```
import UI.Controllers.AuthorizationController;
import Utils.Network;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    private static Network network;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader authLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Authorization.fxml"));
        Parent authRoot = authLoader.load();
        Scene authScene = new Scene(authRoot);
        AuthorizationController authorizationController = authLoader.getController();
        authorizationController.setNetwork(network);
        stage.setTitle("Test");
        stage.setScene(authScene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        network = new Network("localhost", 8500);
        network.connectToServer();
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: выглядит все правильно. дебажить пробовали?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov да, у меня вылетает NullPointer, даже если я засуну класс Network в контроллер и там проинициализирую его. До этого я писал чат на сокетах и там подобной проблемы не было. Уже 3 день не могу понять в чём я ошибся, по разному пробую прописать. И самое интересное каждый раз по telten все сообщения приходят.

Comment: в какой строчке вылезает NPE - где происходит авторизация?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov верно, на отправке сообщения на сервер. Это было когда в контролере соединение устанавливалось (метод network.connectToServer()). Сейчас я конекчусь заранее ещё в мейне и NPE не появляется. По дебагеру текст передается полностью и flush = true, DefaultPromise isDone result = null;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен! Была неверная последовательность в pipeline
Верный код со стороны клиента:

```
 bootstrap.group(clientGroup)
                        .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                        .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                            @Override
                            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
                                channel = socketChannel;
                                socketChannel.pipeline()
                                        .addLast(
                                                new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8),
                                                new LineBasedFrameDecoder(8192),
                                                new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8),
                                                new ChunkedWriteHandler(),
                                                new ClientHandler());
                            }
                        });
```

Со стороны сервера:

```
 b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 100)
                    .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                            p.addLast(
                                    new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8),
                                    new LineBasedFrameDecoder(8192),
                                    new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8),
                                    new ChunkedWriteHandler(),
                                    new FileHandler());
                        }
                    });
```